# Sort rows for a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr, data.table

I am searching for a simple dplyr or data.table solution. I need to sort rows of a large data frame, but only have a solution with for loops.

Here is a minimum example:

```
A = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5')
B = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3')
set.seed(20)
df = data.frame(col1 = sample(c(A,B),8,1), col2 = sample(c(A,B),8,1), col3 = sample(c(A,B),8,1))

  col1 col2 col3
1   B1   B1   A1
2   B2   B1   A5
3   A3   A5   B1
4   B3   B2   B3
5   A2   B2   A2
6   A1   A1   B2
7   A2   A3   A4
8   A5   A5   A1
```

The expected output should be:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1   B1   A1   B1
2   B1   A5   B2
3   B1   A3   A5
4   B2   B3   B3
5   B2   A2   A2
6   B2   A1   A1
7   A2   A3   A4
8   A1   A5   A5
```

So, the order of the rows for the sort algorithm is `c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5')` with one exception. If there is already one of the B's in the first column we continue with the A's.

The next problem is, that I have three more columns in the data frame with different numbers which should be rearranged in the same order as these three columns.

Answer (score 2):

Might be more than a little bit too convoluted, but a `dplyr` and `purrr` option might be:

```
map2_dfr(.x = df %>%
             group_split(cond = as.numeric(grepl("^B", col1))),
         .y = list(vec1, vec2),
         ~ .x %>%
             mutate(pmap_dfr(across(c(starts_with("col"), - pluck(select(.x, "cond"), 1))), 
                             function(...) set_names(c(...)[order(match(c(...), .y))], names(c(...)))))) 

  col1  col2  col3   cond
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 B1    A3    A5        0
2 B2    A2    A2        0
3 B2    A1    A1        0
4 A2    A3    A4        0
5 A1    A5    A5        0
6 B1    A1    B1        1
7 B2    A5    B1        1
8 B3    B2    B3        1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`, `factor` and `sort` twice with different orders.

```r
order1 = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5') #Main order
order2 = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3') #Secondary order for rows with 1st column as "B"
startB <- grepl("B", df[, 1]) #Rows with 1st column being "B"

df <- data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, \(x) sort(factor(x, levels = order1)))))
df[startB, -1] <- t(apply(df[startB, ], 1, \(x) sort(factor(x[-1], levels = order2))))
```

output

```r
  X1 X2 X3
1 B1 A1 B1
2 B1 A5 B2
3 B1 A3 A5
4 B2 B3 B3
5 B2 A2 A2
6 B2 A1 A1
7 A2 A3 A4
8 A1 A5 A5
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution so far:

```
A = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5')
B = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3')
set.seed(100)

N = 20

df_1 = data.frame(col1 = sample(c(A,B),N,1), col2 = sample(c(A,B),N,1), col3 = sample(c(A,B),N,1))
vec = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5')
df_2 = t(apply(df_1,1,function(x)match(x,vec)))

df_3 = t(apply(df_2,1,sort))

tr = rowSums(matrix(df_3 %in% c(1,2,3),nrow(df_3), ncol(df_3))) == 2

change = which((df_3[,2]*tr)!=0)

save = df_3[change,2]
df_3[change,2] = df_3[change,3]
df_3[change,3] = save

df_4 = matrix(vec[df_3],nrow(df_3),ncol(df_3))
```

from `df_2` to  `df_3` the place of the number is changing and I can rearrange the other columns by that.
Looks a little bit complicated